# How to convert xml into array in php?

Tags: input-formats, theming

I want to convert the XML structure below into a PHP array.

```
<BillingApplyRq>
    <FatoryId>xxxxxx</FatoryId> 
    <TotalNum>2</TotalNum> 
    <Records> 
        <Record> 
            <ReturnMsgNo>1</ReturnMsgNo> 
            <ReturnMsg></ReturnMsg> 
            <TradeSeq>00001</TradeSeq> 
        </Record> 
        <Record> 
        <ReturnMsgNo>1</ReturnMsgNo> 
        <ReturnMsg></ReturnMsg> 
        <TradeSeq>00002</TradeSeq> 
        </Record> 
    </Records> 
</BillingApplyRq>
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: thx. i will ask @ stackoverflow in the future.

Comment: Use the core function [drupal_xml_parser_create](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21unicode.inc/function/drupal_xml_parser_create/7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is not related to Drupal but anyway you must convert from XML to array by using the sample code below from PHP.net

```
$simple = "<para><note>simple note</note></para>";
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $simple, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($p);
echo "Index array\n";
print_r($index);
echo "\nVals array\n";
print_r($vals);
```

Ref: [xml_parse_into_struct — Parse XML data into an array structure](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php)